# How can I use my smartphone as an oscilloscope?

Tags: oscilloscope, android

I found this circuit that can make my laptop work as oscilloscope:

[image]

Can this circuit work with my android phone while am using [this app?](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nfx.noscpro)

Comment: Most audio inputs are AC-coupled, so you won't be able to measure DC, and limited to maybe 20 kHz of bandwidth

Comment: THere are audio scopes for Android too.  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nchsoftware.pocketwavepad_free

Comment: One reason the above circuit won't work, is a PC has a separate 3.5 mm jack for a microphone, and a smartphone uses a single four-conductor 3.5 mm jack (TRRS) for both microphone and headphones.

Comment: stereo jakcs no work for audio input in smartphones......!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Google Play page for the app you linked has a section for microphone support which includes a link to an instructable for a circuit:

> ***** Microphone SUPPORT ******
>   The second option is the microphone input to the android device. This can be used to attach a scope lead to the jack socket. More information can be found at the following website.
>   http://www.instructables.com/id/A-Preamplifier-for-Smartphone-Oscilloscopes/
>   Features include, triggering for different impulse and continuous signals. In addition to this there is level measurement and fundamental frequency readings

[image]